# Неправильный вывод функции python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список

```
def generatePaths():
    p = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    r = []

    p[-1] += 1 # Увеличиваем последний элемент массива на 1
    r.append(p)# Добавляем этот массив к r
    p[-1] += 1 # Увеличиваем последний элемент массива на 1
    r.append(p)# Добавляем этот массив к r

    return r
```

Вывод получается:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]]
```

Почему так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что это **один и тот же список** `p` два раза лежит внутри списка `r`. Т.е. фактически у вас список `r` выглядит так:

```
r = [p, p]
```

Когда вы меняете список `p`, эти изменения отражаются в том, что вы видите в списке `r` (два раза).

Хотите, чтобы эти вложенные в `r` списки стали независимыми (разными) списками - делайте копию списка:

```
r.append(p.copy())
```

Хотя это поможет только с одномерными списками. Если там будет больше вложенность, то копировать нужно будет с помощью `deepcopy`.

Answer (score 0):

Ссылка на список p совпадает с ссылкой на список r. Вам потребуется сделать копию списка для созданий новой ссылки на память.

Comment: Дополните свой ответ – например, рабочим кодом или ссылками на документацию.